# Negatively Correlated Events

Tags: probability, terminology

I showed the following inequality to a colleague, where $A$ and the $B_i$ are all *events*:
$$
\Pr\left(A \mid \bigwedge_{i = 1}^n \overline{B_i} \right) \leq \Pr(A)
$$
He summarized, "So $A$ is negatively correlated with the $B_i$."

I have never heard this phrase used to refer to events. Even when it is used with respect to random variables, I'm not sure it is quite the same thing.

Could a more experience probabilist chime in? Does his terminology make sense? Is there a better word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does his terminology make sense?

It does: events $A$ and $B$ are negatively correlated if and only if $\mathbb P(A\cap B)\leqslant\mathbb P(A)\mathbb P(B)$, random variables $X$ and $Y$ are negatively correlated if and only if $\mathbb E(XY)\leqslant\mathbb E(X)\mathbb E(Y)$.

Comment: As surely your colleague would have told you on the spot if only you had asked them.

Comment: I just wanted a second opinion. Thanks.

Comment: I just noticed that I slightly mistyped the inequality by neglecting the complementation. Your answer is still good, but my colleague probably should have said that $A$ is negatively correlated with the complement of the $B_i$s.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that correlation of events is a special case of correlation of variables: just take the indicator functions of the events.

Comment: AustinMohr: You should have left the question as it was, the modification only adds confusion.